# WPF - Adding a label on edges in Graph#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, graph, graph-sharp

I couldn't work with WPF so I used elementHost in Winform.

In my project (graph draw with Graph#) I can draw vertices and edges but I couldn't put label on edges.

Code :

```
string[] vertices = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var g = new BidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>>();

g.AddVertexRange(vertices);

g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[0], vertices[1]));
g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[1], vertices[2]));
g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[0], vertices[2]));

graphLayout.Graph = g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a color legend rather than labels and then color the edges.

```
if (FirstCase
{
    g.AddVertex("A");
    Color edgeColor = Colors.Green;

    g.AddVerticesAndEdge(new MyEdge("A", "B")
    {
        EdgeColor = edgeColor
    });
}
if (SecondCase
{
    g.AddVertex("B");
    Color edgeColor = Colors.Red;

    g.AddVerticesAndEdge(new MyEdge("B", "C")
    {
        EdgeColor = edgeColor
    });
}
```